# Deploy multiple war files of same api

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, openshift, api-gateway

I want to have two war files of the same API and both should be working. How do I do that ?

Note: we are using docker, kubernetes, open shift.

We can have two different services, two diff routes, no issues in that. But I want both the services of same API to run. We can have different URI though.

How do we achieve having two war files for same API.

Is there any API gateway to do this? And if yes, then how to do it ?

Thanks

I read about APIGEE revisions, but it does not talk about two different war files.

Not sure if AWS does it or Azure.

Comment: Are the two war files exactly the same or different versions of the API?

Comment: If you simply want to run multiple instances of your service increase the replicas count on your deployment config.

Comment: Yes, they are exactly same. But eventually one might have sone modifications in future.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could path-based routes be a solution? See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-path-based-routes_route-configuration.

By using path based routes you can have the same base url for many different services and route traffic to each service based on the path.

Or if the goal is to deploy the same API in multiple instances to progressively roll out new versions of the API I would look into https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/applications/deployments/route-based-deployment-strategies.html#deployments-ab-testing_route-based-deployment-strategies. With that strategy you deploy both wars and can decide which of them to route traffic to.

Comment: We can use this. But does it use two different war files for same api ?

Comment: Hmm I probably misunderstand what you're trying to achieve here. I thought you meant the API was split into two parts, each part in their separate war.

Comment: No, I’m not splitting. I would eventually use two instances of same API have two separate war files co-existing

Comment: Why not deploy the service twice then under different names?